# Proc Tabulate rowpctn separate column percent

Tags: sas

I am new to SAS, try to figure out Proc Tabulate more.

```
proc tabulate data=stem_camp1;
class gender pass SUBJECT;
table GENDER, SUBJECT*PASS*(n="count" rowpctn="%");
run;
```

I have a code like this above.

[image]
SAS is calculating percentage BIOS AND MATH, so when I sum up 4 of %, it gets 100%

but I want SAS to calculate percentage BIOS AND MATH separate.

for example like this

```
       BIOS                 MATH
MALE - - 10 100%      10 50%  10 50%
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From helps (my bold):

> **Using PCTN and PCTSUM**
>
> PCTN and PCTSUM statistics can be used to calculate these same percentages. They enable you to manually define denominators. PCTN and PCTSUM statistics print the percentage of the value in a single table cell in relation to the value (used in the denominator of the calculation of the percentage)in another table cell or to the total of the values in a group of cells. By default, PROC TABULATE summarizes the values in all N cells(for PCTN) or all SUM cells (for PCTSUM) and uses the summarized value for the denominator. You can control the value that PROC TABULATE uses for the denominator with a denominator definition.
>
> You place a denominator definition in **angle brackets (< and >)** next to the PCTN or PCTSUM statistic. The denominator definition specifies which categories to sum for the denominator.

So you will want `PCTN<PASS>` instead of `ROWPCTN`.

Here is an example using data set `sashelp.cars`

```
proc tabulate data=sashelp.cars;
  class type origin drivetrain;
  table type, origin*drivetrain*(n pctn<drivetrain>);
run;
```

[image]

Just to be clear, the `ALL` drivetrain means *All Wheel Drive*, and is **not** the *Universal Class Variable ALL*.